# TypeScript shows error when declaring a function

Tags: angular, typescript

When executing my code, a typescript error appears that "require" is not a function, which is why I declared the function beforehand, but now typescript complains that "Modifiers cannot appear here.". Can someone help me?

```
import { Injectable, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  edge : any;

  constructor() {
    declare function require(name: string); // "Modifiers cannot appear here."
    this.edge = require('edge');
  }

  getData(type: string, method: string) {
    var data = this.edge.func({
      assemblyFile: 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Siemens\Automation\Simatic OAM\bin\CC.CommonInterfaces.dll',
      typeName: `CC.CommonInterfaces.${type}`,
      methodName: `${method}`
    });

    return data(null, function(error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? Maybe in a StackBlitz? Also, what exactly are you trying to do? Is edge a dependency that you want to import?

Comment: @Wernerson don't know how to show a minimal working example of this. But I can explain what I'm doing here. I'm basically calling C# functions from a .dll in my DataService and want to use the data (from getData()) in my Angular Project. To call C# functions I need edge.js, which needs to be called with a require() function which typescript does not know about until runtime, which is why I declare the function beforehand but it does not work.

Comment: Why are you even using require? You should be importing... Otherwise, use `declare` in `.d.ts` files.

Comment: It seems to me like edge is a dependency and thus, needs to be imported just like you did with `Injectable` and `ValueProvider` form `@angular/core`. Checkout Rahuls answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly import *edge* instead of using *require*:

```
import { Injectable, ValueProvider } from "@angular/core";

import * as edge from "edge";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {
  constructor() {}

  getData(type: string, method: string) {
    let data = edge.func({
      assemblyFile:
        "C:Program FilesCommon FilesSiemensAutomationSimatic OAM\binCC.CommonInterfaces.dll",
      typeName: `CC.CommonInterfaces.${type}`,
      methodName: `${method}`
    });

    return data(null, function(error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    });
  }
}
```